# Consumiing RestApi with Post method HTTPS call

Tags: https, mule

I want to create a service using mule, call RESTfull services HTTPS by HTTP connector. If I call HTTP not HTTPS with two HTTP connector the services return the JSON Object without setpayload connector, the problem that I face when I call HTTPS service with added **Trust store and key store** the result return as:

> Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration3" protocol="HTTPS" host="es.soa.devstage4.weightwatchers.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">

    <tls:context>
        <tls:trust-store path="client_truststore.jks" password="root123"/>
        <tls:key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="root123" password="root123"/>
    </tls:context>
</http:request-config>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/> 
<flow name="happyFlow">
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/happy" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration3" path="/api/v3/servicing/-/enrollment/status/member/348165668?market=en-us" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
    <http:request-builder/>  </http:request>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try remove port number from your code or replace it with 443 the default port number for HTTPS